# PTIJ: Should I follow "Reform"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Talmud often quotes a certain rabbi by the name of Reform bar Pappa: **רפרם בר פפא**  [Kidd. 81b, Taanit 20b, Berachot 8a, etc.]

I am suspicious of him.  Do I have to follow what he says?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

If you have studied this Gemarah, I assume that at some point, you will be making a siyum? If so, you will be saying the *Hadran*. In it, there is a mention of Rav Papa and his 10 sons one of whom is רפרם בר פפא, or as you call him, "Reform".

No reason to be suspicious of him. He has already reformed your thinking and your habits by the fact that you plan on making a siyum not just on the current masechta but also others.

*Hadran* means "return". When you return to the same masechta, you look at it differently than the first time, so your thinking has already been reformed. You can thank Reform bar Papa for that.

Answer (score 3):

Ecclesiastes 1:15 says

> מְעֻוָּ֖ת לֹא־יוּכַ֣ל לִתְקֹ֑ן
>
> A twisted thing cannot be fixed

Fix is a synonym for reform, meaning that a twisted thing is the opposite of Rabbi Reform bar Pappa. Shlomo HaMelech held up Rabbi Reform as an example, and as such he must be extremely trustworthy.